# How to administrate GCP users on Google Cloud Identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I have a domain on Google Cloud Identity Free Edition to administrate already-existing GCP users.
It seems users on Cloud Identity can use GCP under administration, but users who have already existed on GCP can't be managed on Cloud Identity afterward.

Are there any methods to administrate already-existing GCP users on Cloud Identity afterward?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, share the details. It is possible that you are having [conflicting account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7062710) between your GCP users and the users at Cloud Identity. Here is the way to [resolve conflicting accounts](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7044710?visit_id=636710723399271229-442646635&rd=1)

Comment: @Rahi R As you say, my account was conflicting, but now I already solved.
Although I resolved the problem, somehow my account doesn't appear yet here:[See users with potential conflicting accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640?hl=en)

Comment: I was saying it is possible that you are having conflicting account. Would you please post a answer into the thread saying how you resolved it? It will help the community member. While saying "my account doesn't appear yet [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640?hl=en)", did you mean you do not have conflicting accounts?

Comment: When posting the question here, I had a conflicting account by making the same user at Cloud Identity despite I already had the account at GCP.

Comment: > Would you please post a answer into the thread saying how you resolved it?  
⇒ First, I removed the conflicting account registered at Cloud Identity from the setting screen at Cloud Identity. After that, I resolved by rewriting the temporary e-mail address(janedoe%mydomain.com@gtempaccount.com) at GCP to the original e-mail address.

Comment: > did you mean you do not have conflicting accounts?  
⇒
I don't have conflicting accounts now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [F.Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10267878/f-tommy) mentioned, the issue caused by [conflicting account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640?hl=en) and got resolved by removing conflicting account first.